# How do I edit my original question without rolling back?

Tags: support, comments, editing, revision-history

I asked a question and subsequently a user (and then another one) edited my question. Their edits were tags (thank you) and formatting, both of which I really liked, but I have noticed a grammatical issue (that either they introduced through edits or I overlooked in my original post), which although kind of a picky thing, I do like to clean up my work when I see issues with what I've done.

Additionally, through trying to resolve the issue I originally posted about, I now have updated info about the nature of the question which may help someone else answer it, and I wanted to add that below the original question, but not far below with the running comments.

Unfortunately, when I try to edit the question, it warns me that I am editing an older version of the question and accepting changes will cause the whole thing to rollback to an earlier version.  I noticed the Revision Dropdown at the top of the editing screen, but when I try to select the most recent revision (because that would presumably avoid a rollback) it defaults to the revision prior to that one (but not to my original version).

Am I doing something wrong with my edits? Do I lack permissions to edit based on who did the most recent edit? Should I even be trying to edit this way, or just tack on another comment?

Comment: Can you try it again? Maybe you collided with someone editing your question? It should just let you edit your question.

Comment: Just tried again. The "Rev" Dropdown allows me to select the bottom option (my original), or the middle option (presumably the first edit), but when I select the top one (presumably the most recent edit), the screen refreshes and then the title of the first edit is back in the "Rev" line (along with the rollback warning in the right margin). Reloaded Firefox too, just to make sure. Rather Puzzled.

Comment: ok, how about just clicking "edit" on the question instead of picking it from the revisions screen?

Comment: I think your prior collision theory was correct, because that's how I was going in, and then choosing the revision at the top of the edit screen. I just logged into that question again, though, and this time there was a link at the top to accept an edit...and after accepting, it allowed me to click edit without the rollback warning. The Rev dropdown showed a much more recent edit from the same person I couldn't select earlier (~ 10 hours later).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible things to try:

- Can you try it again? Maybe you collided with someone editing your question? It should just let you edit your question.
- how about just clicking "edit" on the question instead of picking it from the revisions screen?

Answer (score 3):

- You can always edit your question without the need for approval.
- It does not depend on who did the last edit. All edits are equal.
- Always edit the question to add information. Comments are second class citizens and can be cleaned anytime without notice.

We appreciate your concern towards making the site better. That said, lets wait for mods to jump in and clarify whats wrong here.